# Huawei P8 Lite - email client not synchronising with BT email server

Tags: huawei, stock-email-app

Our Huawei P8 Lite (2016 Android 5) email client is not synchronising correctly with the BT mail server.  It picks up all the incoming mails, but does not seem to take account of mails deleted on the server by either the iPad or under webmail. We have three 'routes' into our email - webmail from various Windoze machines, the iPad and the Huawei.

The outgoing IMAP is set to port 25 while the incoming is set to port 110. 'Delete mail from server' is set to 'when I delete from inbox'

Ironically, the old Prestigio (Android 4.4 KitKat) phone with exactly similar settings, except for the ports, does synchronise correctly.

Most puzzled.

Comment: This is a bit confusing: port 25 is SMTP, port 110 is POP3 – but you speak of IMAP :) Second confusing thing: why aren't you using the same port settings on both clients, if it's for the same server? If you configured the P8 with "IMAP" but specified ports for POP3, I wonder you get any mails at all. Could you try with the same settings you use on the Prestigio – or is there any reason you need a different setup that doesn't allow for that?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Izzy,

Your pointing out the confusions in my question woke me up and set me to looking up POP3, SMTP and IMAP.  OK, mea culpa, I should have done this before posting, but better late than never.

The Huawei wizard will set up an email account with port 110 incoming and 25 outgoing if one chooses the POP3 option, which I can only assume that I must have done originally. That is not a good choice as it provides no security and BT will not actually allow emails to be sent on that setting.  Apparently, according to the BT help pages, they require SMTP for authenticating users' sent emails as a way of reducing spam.

What I had really wanted was IMAP to keep emails in synch across the various devices used.  To get that on the P8 Lite it is necessary to choose 'Manual' set up. In so doing it is advisable to choose Secure Socket Layer (SSL) security to avoid one's email address and password being sent as plain text.

IMAP and SSL requires port 993 incoming and port 465 outgoing (SSL and presumably SMTP).

It looks as if Android 5 does not indicate in the account list which protocol has been selected for the account, unlike Android 4.4 which does.

So, I think we have a solution in that the P8lite now sends and receives mails correctly.

Thanks.